# In a Twist message, how should angular velocity be interpreted?

Tags: geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the angular velocity instead a vector whose magnitude is the speed of rotation (in rad/s), and whose direction is the axis of rotation? Or is it something different, like Euler angular velocity (unless those are equivalent)?

I tried to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory#Twist which was linked elsewhere, but it sounds like it describes something different, where rotation can only happen around the axis along which it moves.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376736/in-a-twist-message,-how-should-angular-velocity-be-interpreted?/) by [nnmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/59904/nnmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2021-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe [#9941](https://answers.ros.org/question/9941/twist-message-coordinate-system-convention/) will answer your question, but please follow up if its not clear.

In short, the linear and angular components of twist messages represent the *instantaneous* linear and angular velocities. In most applications (that I have been exposed to), it is common to use the robot's body frame (e.g. base_link) as the default reference frame, because this is typically the frame you have control over. If you need that to be in a specific reference frame, you can use TwistStamped messages, which include the frame in the header.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm fairly sure now that both interpretations are equivalent. The beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZg1GogCC4k) says this too: "[The components] are the instantaneous body rates about the [X, Y, Z] axes".

---

Originally posted by [nnmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/59904/nnmm/) with karma: 351 on 2021-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1